# Ошибка при запросе в Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

При попытке зарегестрироваться я получаю вот такую ошибку:
"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\Kurs\reg\less\reg\reg.php:1) in Z:\home\localhost\www\Kurs\reg\less\reg\reg.php on line 11"

Смотрю её в коде, но непонимаю что или как именно нужно исправить.

```
<?php
 /**
 * Обработчик формы регистрации
 * Регистрация пользователя письмом
 */

 //Ключ защиты
 if(!defined('BEZ_KEY'))
 {
     header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
     exit(file_get_contents('../../404.html'));
 }
```

Comment: А что на первых строках? Выложите код. И тем таких куча: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent+by+

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade да ну, rSO и eSO параллельны, поэтому вопрос, заданный на английском SO не может быть дубликатом вопроса русского SO

Comment: Ошибка сама на английском) И он был задан на rSO) Поправьте меня если что-то не так :)

Comment: В reg.php перед <?php стоит пробел или пустая строка

Comment: В любом случае, перед строчкой header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); произведен вывод информации.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй перекодировать в utf-8 без BOM, перед

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/88173)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @Утка нет, это именно решение, пусть и низкого качества.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну я просто выбрал ближайший по смыслу шаблон, чтобы сказать "что-то с этим надо делать"